# Customize a table on wordpress without CSS?

Tags: html

I try to customize a table on wordpress but without CSS, with only html. I specify that my knowledge is not great.

At the moment I have this:

[That I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akZFx.png)

Here is my current code :

```html
<figure class="wp-block-table is-style-stripes"><table><tbody>

<tr><td><strong>Nom </strong></td><td><strong>Prénom</strong></td><td><strong>S1 / S2</strong></td></tr>

<tr><td>Jack</td><td>Ouille</td><td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">12</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">11</span></td></tr>

<tr><td>Moe</td><td>Amed</td><td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">20</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">19</span></td></tr>

<tr><td>Eric</td><td>Zhumour</td><td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">1</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">2</span></td></tr>

<tr><td>Tom</td><td>Jaidulard</td><td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">11</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">17</span></td></tr>

<tr><td>Marie</td><td>Pleinedegraisse</td><td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">8</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">14</span></td></tr>

<tr><td>Adolphe</td><td>Litière</td><td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">1</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">0</span></td></tr>

</tbody></table></figure>
```

And I would like to achieve this:

[That I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb1a0.png)

Anyone know how to customize the top row with HTML?

Comment: You have to use CSS for that.

Comment: Your question needs more context, are you in the page/post block editor or in a page template? Either way you could do inline styles but not sure why you would want to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow JoJo. You are already using CSS in your HTML (the `wp-block-table`, `is-style-stripes`, `has-inline-color` classes are CSS, as are the inline styles you are using). My encouragement to you would do not be afraid of CSS, it is a great skill to learn.

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly quick responses. I am in a worpress page editor and I am inserting an html block to put my code.
Ok, I don't know how to insert the css into an html block or even just edit the top line.

Comment: What I found on google has not worked so far, after that I have no knowledge of code

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `class="wp-block-table is-style-stripes"` into the table tag, so you get the following. This might work or it might do nothing, depending on other things you haven't mentioned. You won't see a difference here, but you might on your machine. Let me know.

```html
<figure>
  <table class="wp-block-table is-style-stripes">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Nom </strong></td>
        <td><strong>Prénom</strong></td>
        <td><strong>S1 / S2</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td>Ouille</td>
        <td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">12</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">11</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>Amed</td>
        <td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">20</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">19</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eric</td>
        <td>Zhumour</td>
        <td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">1</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">2</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>Jaidulard</td>
        <td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">11</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">17</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Marie</td>
        <td>Pleinedegraisse</td>
        <td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">8</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">14</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adolphe</td>
        <td>Litière</td>
        <td><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #0e12d8;">1</span><br><span class="has-inline-color" style="color: #db1b1b;">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</figure>
```

Also, the `<figure>` tag should probably not be wrapping the table, I think.

Comment: Hello, thanks, no suddenly it didn't change anything